# ID token from Azure AD federation does not contains "roles" claim

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, federated-identity, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I created a Azure B2C tenant and i created custom IDP for Azure Active Directory (AD).
I created the user flow from B2C to federate to the Azure AD and get the access token.

Steps that i have followed.

- Created azure AD application
- Generated a secret
- Created custom roles
- Assigned custom roles to users from AD Enterprise Applications
- Created an IDP in B2C
- Created B2C app
- Created a login policy
- Added IDP for federation
- Run the user flow
- Login by federation

The azure AD successfully retrieves the token (`idp_access_token`) as a result of federation. but the issue is the token that retrieve from the azure AD does not contains roles claim. I have created two app roles and assigned them to user. But i couldn't see any roles inside the token.

I followed following documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps

Isn't this not valid for federations? What is the exact way to get assigned app roles by federation.

[image]

Here is the required details to create B2C IDP.

[image]

How to map these details with scope solution?

Comment: Use https://jwt.ms/ to parse your access token and provide screenshots.

Comment: Are you talking about id tokens or access tokens?

Comment: @CarlZhao I updated the question with screenshot. This is the idp_access_token that contains in main token.

Comment: You are using the wrong api, do not use ms graph api, change your `scope` to web api.

Comment: see:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-registration#exposed-api

Comment: The `ms graph api` uses a v1.0 token. There is no `roles` claim in the token. You need to use a custom api to obtain a 2.0 token. The token will contain the `roles` claim. So you need to expose the api protected by Azure.

Comment: @CarlZhao thank you for your reply. Could you please guide me to the process? Is there a documentation to change the token type or something?

Comment: Wait a minute, I will post the answer and I will list the detailed process.

Comment: @CarlZhao really appreciate it

Comment: I gave a demo using Azure AD. If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.)

Comment: sure it is. appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create two applications in Azure AD, one representing the **client application** and the other representing the **api application**, and then use the client application to call the api application.

First, you need to expose the API of the back-end application protected by Azure and add the client application:

[image]

Next you need to set the api application AppRole, which is your customized role, and it will be displayed in the manifest.

[image]

Then you can assign the role to the user. Go to enterprise application>your api application>Users and groups.

[image]

Next, go to the client application, give your client application access to your backend api:

- Under 'API permissions' click on 'Add permission', then click on the 'My APIs' tab.
- Find your backend application and select the appropriate scope.
- Click 'Add permissions'.
- Grant admin consent for your APIs.

Next, you need to use the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to obtain an access token,which requires you to log in to the user and obtain the authorization code, and then use the authorization code to redeem the access token.

[image]

Parse the v2.0 token, it contains both `scp` claims and `roles` claims.

[image]

Comment: This is really helpful. now i'm waiting for grant admin consent. How did you get the "code" for your postman request?

Comment: @BuddhikaPriyabhashana This is the url where I get the authorization code from the browser:  ```https://login.microsoftonline.com/e4c9ab4e-bd27-40d5-8459-23xxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=5f11e827-4b37-4f1f-aa05-33xxxxxxxxxx
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms/index
&response_mode=query
&scope=api://c848e37d-f64d-4cd8-b9bf-0b2xxxxxxxxxx/read
&state=12345```

Comment: In case of IDP federation i have to add AD details to create IDP that related to my B2C tenant. What are the details that required to create an IDP? I need to add following details.
* metadata url
* client id
* client secret
* scope
* response type Etc.
I updated the question with screen shot.

Comment: @BuddhikaPriyabhashana  Have you seen this document? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-generic-openid-connect

Comment: yes, I already configured it for general scenario. But i need to configure it with newly created scope as you guided me. but the issue is this newly created scope does not have client secret. and what should be the value for IDP configuration? how do i point the IDP to scope that contains user roles.

Comment: I figured it out. Value for the scope field of IDP config is <scope> + openid + profile

Comment: Thanks @CarlZhao How do I get the client secret? Currently I dont have one setup anywhere