# WebAssembly Razor client app return 401 while calling a protected API in Azure with Admin Role

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, bearer-token, blazor-webassembly

I have API protected by Azure AD where Authentication is required to get access data, where I expose the API with only one simple scope for now.

The API and client app both are registered in Azure AD.
Roles are also configured for the API, only a a user with Admin role can call my API.

Do I need to assign this Admin role as well to the client App? or `AccessApi` scope is enough?

```
Scopes  Who can consent     Admin consent display name     User consent display name   State 

api://xx  User              AccessApi                      AccessApi                 Enable
```

And a client application build using `webassembly blazor` also registered in Azure AD, and its configured with `Api permission` to use `delegated` access to `AccessApi`.

```
API / Permissions name  Type       Description   Admin consent required    Status
myApi (1)   

AccessApi              Delegated     AccessApi              No
```

I configured `webassembly blazor` client application to authenticate against azure and get token and use that token to call `myApi`, however I keep getting `loading` but no data is being displayed without any error.

Im not sure what went wrong here ?

`program` class of client application:

```
 private static string scope = @"api://xxx/AccessApi";

...

            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");


            builder.Services.AddScoped<GraphAPIAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

            builder.Services.AddHttpClient("ServerAPI",
                client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44314"))
                .AddHttpMessageHandler<GraphAPIAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

            builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
                .CreateClient("ServerAPI"));

            builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
            {
                builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
                options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add(scope);
            });
```

At `fetch data razor page` I imported all necessary libraries

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
@inject IAccessTokenProvider TokenProvider
@attribute [Authorize]

@inject NavigationManager UriHelper
@inject HttpClient Http

...

data = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<data[]>(@"API-url--runs-locally-on-docker");
```

The authorization message handler class

```
 private static string scope = @"api://xxx/AccessApi";
    public GraphAPIAuthorizationMessageHandler(IAccessTokenProvider provider,
        NavigationManager navigationManager)
        : base(provider, navigationManager)
    {
        ConfigureHandler(
            authorizedUrls: new[] { "https://localhost:44314" },
            scopes: new[] { scope });
    }
```

After authenticated myself with Azure AD account, the client app shows `loading..` but no data is being displayed.
at the console level shows this error.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
```

I followed Microsoft documentation and I'm not sure what I'm missing here.
what could be wrong here ?

**Update**

The Api expose tab:
[image]

Api permission for the client app:
[image]

Comment: You could possibly help us help you by figuring out how far through Main() you get before the crash occurs. I don't have knowledge of this code environment, but you should step through it if you're able, otherwise delete code from the end of Main() backwards until it doesn't crash, and then you know the code you most recently deleted was where it crashed.

Comment: I added more description to the whole picture and work flow im trying to achieve.

Comment: Use https://jwt.ms/ to parse the access token and provide a screenshot.

Comment: I cant see where the token is been send to the Api. the `data = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<data[]>(@"API-url--runs-locally-on-docker");` does that automatically somehow

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of Expose an API of the api application? By the way, you also need to add the client application to the api.    https://i.stack.imgur.com/tG0co.png

Comment: Oh I haven't added the client app to the Api. let me try this first

Comment: I update the question with token screenshot and also expose api tab, the client app still return 401 :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, your `scope` is set incorrectly. You should set the scope to the client id of the **api application** instead of the client id of the client application. In your question, I think your scope should be: `api://7b4d6df9-63cd-4ed7-881bxxx/AccessApi`.

Parse the token and you should see `scp` claim and `roles` claim.

[image]

Comment: Im lost here, can you please explain more? I defined scope in Api and that scope is used by the client application. what is wrong here?

Comment: @ikenahim  The `scope` is only granted to the client application by you, and it will be displayed in the token.

Comment: @ikenahim  Try it out according to my method and see how it turns out.

Comment: I created scope `AccessApi` in the Api and expose this scope, and the client application use this scope. I still dont understand you :/.

Comment: Do you mean the scope has be created in the client application ? not at the API?

Comment: @ikenahim  This `scope` is similar to the permissions of ms graph api. If you want to access the graph api, you need to grant permissions to the application. The truth is the same.

Comment: I attached a screenshot of the API permission for client app - as you can see i already give grant permission to the client app to use API scope `AccessApi` , im not sure if this what you mean

Comment: @ikenahim  This is exactly what I mean.  see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66363001/id-token-from-azure-ad-federation-does-not-contains-roles-claim/66364900#66364900

Comment: @ikenahim  see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pdczb.png

Comment: That exactly my implementation, I think the problem is somewhere else maybe in the config file.

Comment: I figure it out the problem was at `appsettings,json` where I had `clientId` value of client app instead of the clientid of the`Api`. I will test this first to see how the token will be.

Comment: The jwt token has now the clientId of the API instead of clientId of client app, however, I dont see the scope :/

Comment: @ikenahim  It may be that the user or the administrator has not yet consent.

Comment: @ikenahim  But it doesn't matter, you can use the token to call the api to test it and see if an error is reported.

Comment: Im getting different error with `cors policy` tho the api allows any `origin`, I will fix this first and try it. I will mark your question as an answer but i will highlight `apsettings.json` as well as part of the problem. thanks for help :)

Comment: I fixed the `cors` problem, while testing the call to the api the token doesnt have the scope, since the scope doesnt need a `user consent`, do I still need to consent it ?

Comment: Sorry, I just saw the comment, how about it, is the problem solved?