# Client app calls protected Api by Azure AD with Admin Role

Tags: azure, api, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, roles

I'm a bit confused, I have the following implementation:

ASP.net API protected using Azure AD, and users with Admin `role` only can call this API, these roles are configured in Azure AD and assigned to users. the API has one defined scope `AccessApi`.

```
Scopes  Who can consent     Admin consent display name     User consent display name   State 

api://xx  User              AccessApi                      AccessApi                 Enable
```

The client application developed in `WebAssembly blazor` is registered and protected in Azure AD without roles, its configured to use `AccessApi` scope from my Api.

```
API / Permissions name  Type       Description   Admin consent required    Status
myApi (1)   

AccessApi              Delegated     AccessApi              No
```

My confusion is do I need to assign an Admin role for the client application to obtain token which will be used  to access the API or the API scope `accessApi` is enough without any roles?

knowing that users of the client app are the same users of the API just with different roles.

Since same users use both API and client App, is it possible to use `MS Graph` by client App to get JWT token and use that token to call the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to control the user's access to the api based on the role, then you can use **appRole**. Set the appRole of the application and then assign the appRole to the user, then only the user who is assigned the appRole can access the api.

[image]

Next, go to the enterprise application and assign appRole to the user.

[image]

[image]

In addition, never try to use the token of ms graph api to call your custom api. These are two completely different api resources, and you need to request different tokens for different api resources!

Comment: By the way, it is your api application that creates the app role.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have already approles created and assigned to users, my confusion was do I need to add Approle to the client application as well or not ?

Comment: So basically, the client application needs only access to scope defined in the Api?

Comment: @ikenahim  Let me think about it, you should add app role as a permission to the client application. Wait a moment, I will go to Azure ad to take a look.

Comment: @ikenahim  I just looked at it, the app role of the api application does not need to be added to the client application. You only need to add the `scope name` of the api application as a delegated permission to the client application.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have this implementation in place. I thought I was missing something since my Api keeps returning 401 an authorized access when I call my Api from the client application when a user sign in. I thought I missed something in Azure AD configuration. but its clear now :)

Comment: @ikenahim  Yes, but you need to assign the app role created by the api application to the users who need to access it. As described in my answer.

Comment: Yes that already has been done and I tested in swagger. And works perfect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231685/discussion-between-carl-zhao-and-ikenahim).

Comment: @ikenahim  Okay, so do you need other help?

Comment: @ikenahim  If the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Thank this question was part of another question if you can look it at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67214366/webassembly-razor-client-app-return-401-while-calling-a-protected-api-in-azure-w :)

Comment: @ikenahim  Okay, let me take a look.